# How to create server based certification authority in domino server?

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I want to register a user on domino server 9.0 from notes api.

But when I try to, it shows the error:

> no Certificate Authority (CA) configured certifier available for this domain.

Comment: Are you able to manually register users on this server using the Domino Admin client? If you can, then you probably have an error in your code and you're going to need to post it so someone can try to help you. If you cannot manually register users and get the same (or similar) error message, then this is a server configuration question, and it belongs on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: thank you sir for your help...it was a server configuration problem